# Cython returns 0 for expression that should evaluate to 0.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

For some reason, Cython is returning 0 on a math expression that should evaluate to 0.5:

```py
print(2 ** (-1))  # prints 0
```

Oddly enough, mix variables in and it'll work as expected:

```py
i = 1
print(2 ** (-i))  # prints 0.5
```

Vanilla CPython returns 0.5 for both cases. I'm compiling for `37m-x86_64-linux-gnu`, and `language_level` is set to `3`.

What is this witchcraft?

Comment: What compilation settings are you using, and what Python version are you compiling for? Is your `language_level` set to the Python version you're compiling for? (The inconsistency is probably a bug even if you have a mismatch between your `language_level` and your Python version, but this information is important for diagnosing the problem.)

Comment: Edited the question to include these details. 10x

Comment: DavidW it's perfectly right you can try just using 1.0 to make it float: print(2 ** -1.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because it's using C ints rather than Python integers so it matches C behaviour rather than Python behaviour. I'm relatively sure this used to be documented as a limitation somewhere but I can't find it now. If you want to report it as a bug then go to https://github.com/cython/cython/issues, but I suspect this is a deliberate trade-off of speed for compatibility.

The code gets translated to

```
__Pyx_pow_long(2, -1L)
```

where `__Pyx_pow_long` is a function of type `static CYTHON_INLINE long __Pyx_pow_long(long b, long e)`.

---

The easiest way to fix it is to change one/both of the numbers to be a floating point number

```
 print(2. ** (-1))
```

---

As a general comment on the design choice: people from the C world generally expect `int operator int` to return an `int`, and this option will be fastest. Python had tried to do this in the past with the Python 2 division behaviour  (but inconsistently - power always returned a floating point number).

Cython generally tries to follow Python behaviour. However, a lot of people are using it for speed so they also try to fall back to quick, C-like operations especially when people specify types (since those people want speed). I think what's happened here is that it's been able to infer the types automatically, and so defaulted to C behaviour. I suspect ideally it should distinguish between specified types and types that it's inferred. However, it's also probably too late to start changing that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Cython is incorrectly inferring the final data type as `int` rather than `float` when only numbers are involved

The following code works as expected:

```
print(2.0 ** (-1))
```

See this link for a related discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/goVpote2ScY